# Set a QComboBox certain field italic

Tags: qt, qcombobox

I am getting started with QT, and have such a problem.
I need to set the font of a certain field (line) of the `QCombobox` to italic.
Is there any way to do this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Look at [QtComboBox::setItemData](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qcombobox.html#setItemData).

Example:

```
newFont=QFont("FontFamily",italic=True)
myComboBox.setItemData(0, newFont, Qt::FontRole) // Where 0 is your index. Compute as necessary
```

Also check out [this thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-19629.html) which discusses something similar for doing bold.

Comment: May I include something for italic=True part ? Or maybe it has to be in quotes? I am getting an error of undeclared identifier for "italic".

Comment: Have you included QFont with `#include <QFont>`? It should work, `italic` is part of the [constructor](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qfont.html#QFont-2).